# Problem with grails email confirmation plug-in only with run-war

Tags: email, grails, grails-plugin, run-war

I'm using the email-confirmation plug-in and it's working fine when using run-app. However if I run-war, it gives me the following error upon confirmation sendout:

[...] No signature of method: com.grailsrocks.emailconfirmation.PendingEmailConfirmation.save() [...]

After further trying, it seems that this even happens only with certain e-mail addresses (e.g. with German tlds, but not having umlauts or something).

I have no idea why this happens or how I could narrow down the problem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution - renaming the "conf" variable in PendingEmailConfirmation to "confirmation" did the trick. Maybe "conf" is a somewhat reserved word or anything? Anyway, it obviously solved my problem. Perhaps this can be changed in the next version - doesn't do any harm anyway.